# What is a field of odd characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have some problem finding info about what a field of odd characteristic is?

An example:

> Let $K$ be a field of odd characteristic. In [5], Bernstein and Lange
>   introduce Edwards curves defined by  $x^2 + y^2 = c^2(1 + dx^2y^2)$
>   where $c, d ∈ K$ with $cd(1 − dc^4) \neq 0$. In [1], this form is
>   generalized to twisted Edwards form defined by
>
> $$ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$$

Comment: A field of odd characteristic is a field having characteristic $p$ with $p\ne2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the smallest integer $p>0$ satisfying
$$0_K=\underbrace{1_K + 1_K \dots + 1_K}_{p \text{ times.}}$$
which is odd (specifically, it is a prime greater than 2.) There is a chance the writer was commenting on how weird the field is, but I would not think so (this is a joke.)

Comment: +1 for the "joke"...

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic of a field is always a prime number.

Thus, a field of odd characteristic is a field having characteristic $p$ with $p\ne2$.